# Kill a process which is listening on port 8080

Tags: windows-7, prompt

I perform the following on Win7 32-Bit in the command prompt:

```
netstat -ano | findstr 8080
```

it returns with:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1896
```

how might I kill this process?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In windows you can use `taskkill /pid 1896`

See the reference at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Comment: It tells me access is denied.

Comment: Open a command prompt with the option "Run as Administrator". If you still have the same problem, then get the utility `Process Explorer`.

Comment: Horray! After running as administrator and performing: TaskKill /PID 1896 /F it solves my problem!

Comment: On Windows 10, taskkill did not work for me, even as Administrator, and even with `/F`. So I needed to use Process Explorer and go kill/delete all the relevant processes (which for me were 'ssh' and 'ssh-agent'.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Git BASH** then you can try with below command

```
taskkill //pid 1896
```

Not the extra back slash here, otherwise it will throw error of invalid argument.

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt and execute:

```
for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":8080" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %a
```

If you want to do it in a .bat, replace **%a** for **%%a**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Josep's command above in a script because we have a problem where MS werfault.exe (Dr Watson) steals port 8080 from our proxy server.

It's a great command, but the find "8080" will also find a port of e.g 18080 or a process id that has 8080 in it. Subsequently the wrong task could be killed.

Can be improved by changing the find string to ":8080 "  (note the trailing space)

Thanks

Comment: Nice, thanks! :) I have edited my solution based upon your modification!

Answer (score 1):

- The source code for this kill script can be found [here](https://github.com/Git-Leon/bashrc/blob/76920cbc76/aliases/kill-port.sh)
- The source code for the alias-initialization can be found [here](https://github.com/Git-Leon/bashrc/blob/76920cbc76/register-aliases.sh#L24)
- The following bash script, (`kill-port.sh`) successfully kills a port when called.
- It is advised that you create an alias for this shell script

  - `alias kill-port=$pathToScript/kill-port.sh`
- Creating an alias will enable the expression below in the terminal

  - `kill-port 8080`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" ]
  then
    processIds=$(netstat -a -n -b -o | grep $1 | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g" | cut -d ' ' -f6)        
    { #try 
        for processId in $processIds; do
          taskkill /PID /F "$processId" 2>/dev/null
        done 
    } || { # catch
        for processId in $processIds; do
          taskkill //F //PID "$processId"
        done 
    }
fi
```

- Why is there a try / catch?

  - The *try* block is an attempt to kill the specified port in non-gitbash environments.
  - The *catch* block transliterates the *try* block to a cygwin expression for the gitbash terminal
  - This allows the script to be ran in any bash or cygwin environment

Answer (score -1):

For me following works on windows 10, so you guys can also try !!

First of all, find all the process which are running ona port.

For that use following command in cmd:

```
                                 netstat -ano | findstr <port_number>
```

After finding all the process running on a port, 
just use below command to 
terminate the process 
you want to terminate :

```
                    taskkill /F /pid  10608
```

10608 is the process which is going to be terminated.

Comment: This answer is pointless since it duplicates the already accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

in linux u can use for kill process permanently

```
kill -9 PID
```

ex.
I am going to kill `httpd` process and httpd pid is 7452 ok.
then

```
#kill -9 7452
```

But make sure u can use this process only for linux .

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using Windows **not** Linux